# Python For each checkbox column checked on HTML get columns value

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to get data from a table from an HTML that I created, that table has data from a table from a sqlite database.

So, for each checkbox marked in that table, I need to get the data from that row.

However, I am only receiving data from the first line, even if I mark several lines.

I've tried using the getlist, and creating an array, but without success. Since I am still learning from Flask and etc., I already looked for examples but I also couldn't find a solution.

My HTML table:

[image: HTML Table]

**HTML code:**

```
<form method="POST">
            <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id_Game</th>                
                        <th style="width: 800px;">Game</th>
                        <th style="width: 100x;">Critic Score</th>
                        <th style="width: 100px;"><input type="checkbox" id="all" onclick="checkAll(this)"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for game in games.items %}
                    <tr>                
                        <td name="ID_GAME" id="ID_GAME">{{ game.ID_GAME}}</td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="ID_GAME" value="{{ game.ID_GAME }}" />
                        <td name="NM_GAME"> {{ game.NM_GAME}} </td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="NM_GAME" value="{{ game.NM_GAME }}" />
                        <td name="NR_CRITICSCORE">{{ game.NR_CRITICSCORE}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="one_checkbox" name="one_checkbox">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
            {% else %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submitoff()">Submit</button>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
        </form>
```

**Python code:**

```
@main.route('/games/<int:page_num>', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def games(page_num):
    games = V_GAMES.query.paginate(per_page=10, page=page_num, error_out=True)

    if request.method =='POST':
        if request.form.getlist('one_checkbox'):

            ID_USER = current_user.id
            ID_GAME = request.form.get('ID_GAME')
            NM_GAME = request.form.get('NM_GAME')
            IC_PLAYED = "YES"
            SYSDATE = datetime.datetime.now()

            # create new user with the form data. Hash the password so plaintext version isn't saved.
            addprofile = USERGAMESPLAYED(ID_USER=ID_USER, ID_GAME=ID_GAME, NM_GAME=NM_GAME, IC_PLAYED=IC_PLAYED, DT_PLAYED=SYSDATE)

            # add the new user to the database
            db.session.add(addprofile)
            db.session.commit()

            flash('Games have been successfully added to your profile.')

        if not request.form.get('one_checkbox'):            
            flash('You have to check at least one game to add to your profile!')
    
    return render_template('games.html', games=games)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this two lines of code

```
ID_GAME = request.form.get('ID_GAME')
NM_GAME = request.form.get('NM_GAME')
```

You are always getting the data from the first line since you are using get but not gelist.

The way I would do this is to first modify your checkbox

```
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" id="one_checkbox" name="one_checkbox" value="{{ your_game_id }}">
</td>
```

So that you can get all the games that are checked by their id

```
print(request.form.getlist('one_checkbox'))
[checked_game_id_1, checked_game_id_2, ...]
```

Then, use a for loop to loop through the checked games, use their id to get `ID_GAME` and `NM_GAME`, and do your processing.

**EDIT**

To get NM_GAME by ID_GAME

```
for id in request.form.get('one_checkbox')
    game = V_GAMES.query.filter_by(ID_GAME=id).first()
    nm_game = game.NM_GAME
```

Comment: You helped me to adjust the checkbox and set the value for each one, through the ID he is bringing the correct data, thank you very much! However, it is not bringing the NM_GAME differently. And when I try to insert the data in a sqlite table, it gave an error because the ID_GAME is probably in an array (although I tried with a loop). Could you help me, please? I'm having trouble with that.

Comment: Are you using request.form.getlist('ID_GAME')? This will return an array of all ID_GAME in the table. I am not sure about the purpose of having hidden inputs. Logically speaking, the only way you know if the user checked a checkbox is getting an array of all checked games using request.form.getlist('one_checkbox') (which has ID_GAME in it). You will then have to find the NM_GAME using the retrieved ID_GAME.

Comment: I added that <td> hidden inputs, because that's the only way I found to get those data from those columns. How can I retrieve the rest of the columns from the data when I find the ID? I tried with `request.form.get` and `request.form`, otherwise that's another way? I used `for checkbox in request.form.getlist('one_checkbox'):`, but checkbox retrieve only the ID. I'm sorry, but I'm really stuck at this.

Comment: You have the data. You do not need to put it into the column and retrieve it. I noticed that you have a V_GAME model for your games. I will update my answer right now.

Comment: You can use a database query to get the NM_GAME by ID_GAME. I have updated my original answer :).

Comment: I hadn't really thought about taking the data from my own table, since I had the game ID. You really saved me, thank you very much!